# mySQL multi-table update - Update one table by picking a distinct value in another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
--Table a--
uid, name
1, Fred Jones
2, Mary Smith
3, Chip Green
etc.

--Table b--
uid, name, thing, back_ref
1, Fred Jones, one thing, 1
2, Fred Jones, another thing, 1
3, Mary Smith, a thing, 2
4, "Chip" Green, one thing, NULL
5, "Chip" Green, another thing, NULL
6, "Chip" Green, a third thing, NULL
```

So, there are (possibly) multiple rows in table b for each person in table a.

I recently added the back_ref column and wanted to match names to create a back reference. I have already run an update query that used a sub-query to match the rows on the names and fill in the "back_ref" field in table b from table a's uid. Of course, since "Chip" Green's name differs slightly between a and b, that didn't happen for his rows (there was a problem with how the data was loaded before it got to me). I wrote a little function that I can use to force the connection for just the few rows that have this problem (by ignoring double-quotes and such) like this:

```
WHERE CleanUpName(a.name) = CleanUpName(b.name) and b.back_ref is NULL
```

I have an update statement to fill in the back_ref, but I want to write an update statement that will copy a name from any of the associated rows in table b into table a's name field to correct it (just in the cases where the comparison failed.)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You might want to clean up table b and run the same update.Are the names in tableb messed up with the same pattern?That is the first name is in quotes?

Comment: The names in table b are correct. Somehow, when table a was loaded something or someone stripped all the punctuation out of the names. So I'm trying to put the correct names into table a again. I'm having trouble figuring out how to both limit my update to NULLs in table b's back_ref field AND update table a. If I join them in the UPDATE statement, then I have several rows for "Chip" - not just one. I guess I don't care if I update Chip's name in table a three times, but I don't think SQL will like that anyway. I need an UPDATE DISTINCT or something...

Comment: Some of the names in table b are of the form Charles "Chip" Green - not always the first name is quoted. And some of the ones in table a have extra blanks leading, trailing or embedded. Unfortunately, its what I've got to work with and it's a pretty large database, so performance is a bit of an issue.